# Replacing one specific item inside a 2dArray in numPy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to script a battleship game (i.e. where you say "B4" and the enemy says "HIT")

Actually i'm trying to let the pc randomly pick the ship position. Everything is ok but now i need to change the value of the choosen box in "X" or something different.

```py
from random import *
import numpy as np

def nuovaPartita():

    campo = np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
    navi = [
        [True, True],
        [True, True],
        [True, True],
        [True, True],
        [True, True, True],
        [True, True, True],
        [True, True, True],
        [True, True, True, True],
        [True, True, True, True],
        [True, True, True, True, True]
    ]

    direzioni = [0,1,2,3]



    for x in navi:
        posTrovata = False
        while posTrovata == False:

            lenNave = len(x)
            scegliCasella = choice(choice(campo))
            scegliDirezione = choice(direzioni)
            posCasella = np.where(campo == scegliCasella)

            R = int(posCasella[0])
            C = int(posCasella[1])
            print("============================\nHo scelto la casella: {}\nLunghezza nave: {}".format(scegliCasella, lenNave))

            if scegliDirezione == 0:                     
                print("Vado in alto")
                chunk = campo[R-(lenNave - 1): R+1, C]
                if int(chunk.shape[0]) < lenNave:
                    print("Assolutamente")
                    posTrovata = False
                else: 
                    posTrovata = True
                    print("La nave si trova nelle caselle")
                    print(chunk)

            elif scegliDirezione == 1:
                print("Vado a destra")
                chunk = campo[R, C: C + lenNave ]
                if int(chunk.shape[0]) < lenNave:
                    print("Assolutamente")
                    posTrovata = False
                else: 
                    posTrovata = True
                    print("La nave si trova nelle caselle")
                    print(chunk)


            elif scegliDirezione == 2:
                print("Vado in basso")
                chunk = campo[R: R+lenNave, C]
                if int(chunk.shape[0]) < lenNave:
                    print("Assolutamente")
                    posTrovata = False
                else: 
                    posTrovata = True
                    print("La nave si trova nelle caselle")
                    print(chunk)


            elif scegliDirezione == 3:
                print("Vado a sinistra")
                chunk = campo[R, C - lenNave: C]
                if int(chunk.shape[0]) < lenNave:
                    print("Assolutamente")
                    posTrovata = False
                else: 
                    posTrovata = True
                    print("La nave si trova nelle caselle")
                    print(chunk)


    print(campo)


def main():
    nuovaPartita()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

Now, if i display the field (named "campo") I get this

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29]
 [30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39]
 [40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49]
 [50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59]
 [60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69]
 [70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79]
 [80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89]
 [90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99]]
```

Now, assume I have a warship on [54, 55, 56, 57] and a warship on [31, 41, 51], how could I replace those boxes int with, for example, "x"?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply change a value in campo by accessing it’s index.  campo is a list of lists, so accessing number 56 can be done by accessing the value at index 6 of the list at index 5, like this:

```
campo[5][6] = 'x'
```

You could even generalize this to:

```
def update_campo(campo, number):
    campo[number // 10][number % 10] = 'x'
    return campo

for i in range(56, 60):
    campo = update_campo(campo, i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this chunk of code

```py
if posTrovata == True:
                for x in chunk:
                    rCas = int(np.where(campo == int(x))[0])
                    cCas = int(np.where(campo == int(x))[1])
                    campo[rCas][cCas] = 100
```

returns

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```